# Save values on the form or wizard without creating custom object

Tags: apex

I am creating a wizard in which I have created a VF page which consist of rules.
I want to store this rules, so that when user opens this wizard again I can get all the rules he has used before.

Creating a custom object to store this value is an option but as I am going to have only one setting i.e one record for this custom setting. So creating an object and adding its fields is not a good idea.

Also I have tried to store these values in custom settings, I have serialized all the input values and was  trying to store string in custom setting. But my serialized string is exceeding string length of 255 characters. And in custom settings I am not able to put text area long or more then 255 characters.

Comment: Can't you break them up into smaller strings?  Is there a reason that you need in one custom setting field?  Can't you just create more custom setting fields to hold the different values?

Comment: Another approach that might or might not work for you is to use Document objects to hold long JSON strings. You can base the name on e.g. the UserInfo.getUserId() and put these documents in a specific folder.

Comment: I assume that you don't know how many rules user will use so creating an custom object with static field number is not a good idea? How about breaking each rule to one record and upsert the rules each time the user changes them?